# Unexpected Token - Jest for existing React + Web-pack app

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, webpack, jestjs

I have a simple React app. I am trying to configure Jest(Testing framework for React) to my existing react app. When I try to run the test cases from npm test, it gives me the following error:

```
> openmrs-owa-built-in-reports@0.1.0 test D:\OpenMRS\OWA\openmrs-owa-built-in-reports
> jest

 FAIL  app\js\__tests__\reports\common\ReportAsTableView.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    D:/OpenMRS/OWA/openmrs-owa-built-in-reports/app/js/__tests__/reports/common/ReportAsTableView.test.js: Unexpected token (14:16)
        12 |
        13 |         const rendered = renderer.create(
      > 14 |                 <ReportAsTableView reportUUID="e451ae04-4881-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33"
           |                 ^
        15 |                 reportParameters= {params} />
        16 |         );
        17 |         expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapShot();

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.948s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

My React app is bundled using webpack. I will be much thankful if anyone could tell me how to solve this problem.

Here is my test case:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ReportAsTableView from '../../../components/reports/common/ReportAsTableView';

describe('ReportAsTableView renders correctly ', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const params = {
            "startDate": "2017-05-05",
            "endDate": "2017-10-05"
        };

        const rendered = renderer.create(
                <ReportAsTableView reportUUID="e451ae04-4881-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33" 
                reportParameters= {params} />
        );
        expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapShot();
    });
});
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "openmrs-owa-built-in-reports",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "built-in reports for reference application",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/openmrs-owa-openmrs-owa-built-in-reports"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "archiver": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "on-build-webpack": "^0.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.10.5",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "yargs": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist && rimraf coverage*",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --progress --colors --mode=production --target=web",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean && webpack --progress --colors --mode=dev --target=web",
    "build:prod": "npm run test && npm run build",
    "build:deploy": "webpack --progress --colors --mode=deploy --target=web",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch --mode=deploy --target=web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "OpenMRS",
    "Open",
    "Web",
    "App"
  ],
  "author": "JudeNiroshan",
  "license": "MPL-2.0",
  "jest": {
    "automock": false,
    "browser": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "./app/js/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "./app/js/__mocks__/fileTransformer.js"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "roots": [
      "./app/js/__tests__"
    ],
    "testRegex": ".*.test.js",
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```

All other posts I've seen similar to this problem talks about a file named as babelrc. But in my project I couldn't find such a file. Here is the project -> [link](https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/openmrs-owa-built-in-reports)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured Babel in your [webpack config](https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/openmrs-owa-built-in-reports/blob/7cdfe2f94848b7d88fb1031d6ad9177f7bdc6e63/webpack.config.js#L170) and this will only apply to webpack. When other tools, like Jest, use Babel, they won't see that configuration because they don't look at the webpack config. You can use a [`.babelrc`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) file to configure Babel and that will apply to anything that runs Babel (not just webpack).

Using a `.babelrc` is usually preferred as you want to have a general babel config, and if you need to override a setting, you can still do that in the specific application like in the webpack config.

Create the following `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

With that, you can remove the `presets` option in your webpack config because it will use the `.babelrc`. Note that the [`cacheDirectory` option](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options) is specific to `babel-loader` and is not used to configure the underlying Babel.

You also have a typo in your test, `toMatchSnapShot()` should be [`toMatchSnapshot()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchsnapshotoptionalstring).

```
expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That means, it is a must to have a `.babelrc` file in my root directory in order to run Jest. (You deserve more than just 25 rep. Let me do something with that :D)