# Can't set up the HMR: stuck with "Waiting for update signal from WDS..." in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So I'm setting up a minimal configuration for my React app, and I faced that `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` message in console and my browser page doesn't reflect any changes

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491310/cant-get-webpack-2-hmr-react-to-work/43609827) solution I had tried to add `@babel/preset-env`, but it had no success. And I don't think that it's the root of the problem, since even if I change my `index.js` file, no changes applied in the browser

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    watchContentBase: true,
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [new HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

`src/index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render as r } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

r(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

`src/App.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello from React Version: {React.version}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and my `.babelrc` conf:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Comment: Just use this: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started It takes care of everything.

Comment: @ChrisG I want to set it up from scratch :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so apparently [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1604) is what causing the issue. I added

```
disableHostCheck: true
```

to my webpack `devServer` config and it worked (note that it's just a workaround).

And I have no idea why there were no error messages in windows 10 (after I had booted my app from win7 the console was spamming with `Invalid Host/Origin header`

Comment: Worked for me too. Did you figure out the core issue? In my case, the app works fine standalone, but ultimately I'm porting it inside of a CRM so for development I have to reference `localhost:8080/dist/app.js` To get the functionality and HMR. Worked fine for my other projects... this one not sure what the deal is. Let me know if you have any additional insight please. Thanks!

Comment: where this line needs to be added?

Comment: @SravanKumar `webpack.config.js` as far as I remember

Comment: @Oscar can you please tellme your mail id... I'm having doubts which i want t clear. I'm beginner in react.

Comment: In webpack v4, this was superseded by `allowedHosts: 'all'`.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue being stuck at `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` while using `webpack` 5, `webpack-dev-sever` and `browserslist`.

It seems to be a bug when using `browserslist` with `webpack` 5 and `webpack-dev-sever` as [answered by chenxsan here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988081/4316314). More info about the bug can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758).

The solution (for now) is to add `target: 'web'` to the webpack config. Example:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    hot: true
  },
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'development',
  [...]
}
```

Comment: I've been bashing my head for 2 hours now unable to make neither livereload nor HMR work until I found your comment. THANK YOU!

Comment: Interesting, so I am needing to use `target: ["web", "es5"]` to support IE11, but that breaks HMR apparently...

Comment: If anyone, like me, needs to use `target: ["web", "es5"]`, you need at least v4.0.0-beta.1 of `webpack-dev-server` installed. Reference: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758#issuecomment-813279691

Answer (score 6):

Having this error can mean that, you have a recursion, that is importing a component within itself. This can happen during refactoring of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Home this helps someone.

I got this problem and apparently what caused my problem was having iframes with src="/blank.html" and I solved it by adding a proxy

```
proxy: {
    '/*.html': {
        target: 'https://something.else',
        changeOrigin: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WIPE AND REPLACE NODE MODULES:
My REACT project console read “Waiting for update signal from WDS…" followed by every module not being found.

What worked for me was to remove and re-install my node modules with these two lines in my terminal. Then my app worked again.

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn install (or npm install)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using `Firebase` as your backend, which was the case in my situation. You might have **exhausted your daily quota** and because of that, you may not be able to read/write or even access any components that will be using firebase.

Due to this, I was constantly getting `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` in the console. You might have your warnings disabled (which again was the case in my situation) and bcoz of that you won't be seeing that warning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was cause by a syntax error in my code.Check your code for errors that go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are getting this error in Angular, in my case the problem was that I was using `--live-reload false` with `--hmr` at the same time. So `ng serve --live-reload false --hmr` will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I think removing the node_modules is not the best option. I believe most node_module came with the old version webpack that mean we need to update the new version TIPS(If you took the route of using webpack-dev-middleware instead of webpack-dev-server, please use the webpack-hot-middleware package to enable HMR on your custom server or application.)
Attached please read the link for a better implementation on the HMR webpack (https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/#enabling-hmr.) Good luck!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) . Try to add some notes about what your answer does better or differently compared to the already accepted one !