# How to resolve the issue "Waiting for update signal from WDS..."?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

```
export default function SinglePost() {
  const location =useLocation();
  const paths=location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  console.log(paths);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getpost= async () => {
      const res=axios.get("/posts/"+paths)
      console.log(res);
    }
  },[paths])
```

What should I do?

I checked out the some [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905253/cant-set-up-the-hmr-stuck-with-waiting-for-update-signal-from-wds-in-cons)

The first solution says to change the webpack.config.js file and I am not able find that file. And is this the correct solutions.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70862970/12737879) it says that's not an error; in the same post the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61032298/12737879)'s solution may cause you problems later

Comment: As a side-note you have forgotten `await` operator at your `axios.get` call

Comment: Thank you for pointing the  Await operator mistake. But it still doesn't work . and the First solution does not solves the problem it just stop print the error message. I still cannot console log my res.